# How to format a number using jQuery? Ex. 119.0484 I want to format it to "9999.99"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, math, input

How to format a number using jQuery? Ex. 119.0484 I want to format it to "9999.99"?

How can I achieve this? Can you give a sample code? Thank you very much to those who can help me with this. I've tried this code. But whenever I click a radio button again the value is changing. I think the problem here is the structure of my code. But also want to know if .toFixed(2) really solved the 9999.99 format..
HTML

```
  <input type="radio" name="unitScale" id="opt1" onclick="changeUnit()" checked class="roleAuthorization"><label>Metric (Kg&Cm)</label>
  <input type="radio" name="unitScale" id="opt2" onclick="changeUnit()" class="roleAuthorization"><label>English (Lbs&In)</label>
```

Script

```
function changeUnit() {
    var requestNum = $("#requestNum").val();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    if ($("#opt1").is(":checked")) {
        $("#kg").removeAttr("style");
        $("#lbs").attr("style", "display:none;");
        $("#cmtrs").removeAttr("style");
        $("#inches").attr("style", "display:none;");
        convertToMetric();    
    } else if ($("#opt2").is(":checked")) {
        $("#kg").attr("style", "display:none;");
        $("#lbs").removeAttr("style");
        $("#cmtrs").attr("style", "display:none;");
        $("#inches").removeAttr("style");
        convertToEnglish();       
    }
}

function convertToMetric(){
    var weight = $("#weight").val();
    var height = $("#height").val();
    if ((weight != "")&&(height != "")){
        weight = weight / 2.2046;
        weight = weight.toFixed(2);
        height = height / 0.39370;
        height = height.toFixed(2);
        $("#weight").val(weight);
        $("#height").val(height);
    }
}

function convertToEnglish(){
    var weight = $("#weight").val();
    var height = $("#height").val();
    if ((weight != "")&&(height != "")){
        weight = weight / 2.2046;
        weight = weight.toFixed(2);
        height = height / 0.39370;
        height = height.toFixed(2);
        $("#weight").val(weight);
        $("#height").val(height);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mean that you want to display a number with two decimal places, use [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Comment: Question really shows a serious lack of research effort. This topic is not hard to search on web. Please try searching before asking

Comment: I am creating a simple application that will convert Kg to Lbs if I check the English radio button. Ex. I input 56 Kg that will be converted to 123.459 the requeirement is to format it to 9999.99 format.

Comment: @nnnnnn I've tried .toFixed(2) but whenever I click a radio button again the value is changing.

Comment: @charlietfl ofcourse i've done a research before asking. I've tried .toFixed(2) it works at first, but whenever i want to convert it again from English to Metric the value is changing.

Comment: then that information should have been part of your problem statement otherwise it appears that no attempt has been done to solve this yourself. Asking *"how to" vs *"how to fix this code"* are 2 very different things and the latter is the way this site works. Should definitely not ask *"Can you give a sample code"*. Then it looks like you just want others to do your work for you

Comment: @charlietfl sorry I'm not a perfect person. Don't worry I'll keep that in my mind so that my question will not irritate you. Just a newbie here sorry master.

Comment: Ramil - Please [edit] your question to show the relevant part of your existing code. We can then help you with why it is going wrong.

Comment: Understand... many come here and do not do any research. Try to edit your question now with what you tried. Should also read [ask]

Comment: @charlietfl I've edited the question.. I hope I give the details you're looking..

Comment: @RamilSignh much better! The whole idea here is to help fix and learn from problems ... not start all over from scratch

Comment: Not sure where you call this from though. Showing full context and relevant html would help also

Comment: If the problem is that converting from Metric to Imperial and then back to Metric doesn't give the same number you started with, that's because you've rounded twice in the process. Also your `convertToMetric()` and `convertToEnglish()` functions are the same as each other. (The to English one should use `*`, not `/` in its calculations.)

Comment: I edited it again kindly checkout..

Comment: @nnnnnn you're right. thanks man :)

Comment: @nnnnnn my problem with .toFixed(2) is that when I input for example 171 and covert it to english it will turn to 67.32 which is right. But when I convert it again to Metric the 171 that I enter became 170.99..

Comment: Yes, because as I said in my previous comment you are rounding, twice. That is, each time you convert you throw away some of the precision, so obviously when you convert back you don't get quite the same number. (You could try to keep the unrounded result in a variable for later use, but then how do you know the difference between when the user clicks both radios in a row and when they manually type in 67.32?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear.

But it seems you are looking to fix the decimal points. If it is so ,you can  check and use [**toFixed**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method.

```
// With rounding
var x = 119.0484;
document.write('<pre>'+x.toFixed(2)+'</pre>')


// Without rounding
var val = (Math.floor(100 * x) / 100).toFixed(2);
document.write('<pre>'+val+'</pre>')
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/drcxzsy7/1/)